# change style of input placeholder with java script

Tags: javascript, css, placeholder

I tried to change the color of the placeholder by adding a new class, so that the color property is overwritten. However, it does not seem to work.
Following code is intended to change the placeholder color from green to red, however it is changed from green to default black/gray.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <input class="class" id="id" type="" name="" placeholder="placeholder text">
</body>
<style type="text/css">
  .class::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    green;
  }
  .class2::-moz-placeholder {
    color:  red !important;
   }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("id").className+="class2";</script>
</html>
```

Where is the mistake or which alternative does work?

Comment: You need to separate css classes with a space, ie `.className += ' class2'`. Why not just replace the class though? There's nothing in `class` that isn't in `class2`

Comment: Voting to close as a *typo*

Comment: indeed, i forgot, thanks for the quick response

Comment: I reduced the problem to the minimum, in the original problem there are defined more properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("id").className += "class2";
```

turns the class name into `"classclass2"`. Because there is no corresponding class `classclass2` in your CSS, this element is ignored. Add a space before the new class name:

```
document.getElementById("id").className += " class2";
```

or use the more modern `classList` approach:

```
document.getElementById("id").classList.add("class2");
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice modern solution for this for ES5 ready browser is to use the classList method from a selected DOMnode. This way you will not run into concat problems when rendering fragments to the DOM.

```
document.getElementById("id").classList.add("class2")
```